# how to use Boolean array or LogicalVector Rcpp::List getPIcvalue() and RcppExport SEXP mypackage5_getPIcvalue()

Tags: c++, arrays, r, boolean, rcpp

I am trying to install `mypackage5` package using `RcppEigen.package.skeleton()`, while there is something wrong with `LogicalVector&` in `Rcpp::List getPIcvalue` and `RcppExport SEXP mypackage5_getPIcvalue` function. Here is the C++ function with `bool varIn[]`,

```
#include <RcppEigen.h>
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Eigen;
using namespace Rcpp;
using std::string;

// getPIcvalue
Rcpp::List getPIcvalue(int p, bool nest, string criteria, bool varIn[], bool findIn, int n,const MatrixXd& Y,const MatrixXd& Xf,const MatrixXd& X0,double sigma);
RcppExport SEXP mypackage5_getPIcvalue(SEXP pSEXP,SEXP nestSEXP,SEXP criSEXP,SEXP varInSEXP,SEXP findInSEXP,SEXP nSEXP,SEXP YSEXP,SEXP XfSEXP,SEXP X0SEXP,SEXP sigmaSEXP) {
BEGIN_RCPP
    SEXP __sexp_result;
    {
        Rcpp::RNGScope __rngScope;
        Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< int >::type p(pSEXP );
        Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< bool >::type nest(nestSEXP );
        Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< string >::type criteria(criSEXP );
        Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< bool >::type varIn[](varInSEXP );
        Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< bool >::type findIn(findInSEXP );
        Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< int >::type n(nSEXP );
        Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< const MatrixXd& >::type Y(YSEXP );
        Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< const MatrixXd& >::type Xf(XfSEXP );
        Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< const MatrixXd& >::type X0(X0SEXP );
        Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< double >::type sigma(sigmaSEXP );
        Rcpp::List __result = getPIcvalue(p, nest, criteria, varIn[], findIn, n, Y, Xf, X0, sigma);
        PROTECT(__sexp_result = Rcpp::wrap(__result));
    }
    UNPROTECT(1);
    return __sexp_result;
END_RCPP
}
```

when I run `Rcmd INSTALL --build mypackage5`, error is:

```
* installing *source* package 'mypackage5' ...
** libs

*** arch - i386
cygwin warning:
  MS-DOS style path detected: C:/R/R-31~1.1/etc/i386/Makeconf
  Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/c/R/R-31~1.1/etc/i386/Makeconf
  CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
  Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
    http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
g++ -m32 -I"C:/R/R-31~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG    -I"C:/Users/LJH/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/Rcpp/include" -I"C:/Users/LJH/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/RcppEigen/include" -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
RcppExports.cpp: In function 'SEXPREC* mypackage5_getPIcvalue(SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP)':
RcppExports.cpp:27:68: error: expected primary-expression before ']' token
make: *** [RcppExports.o] Error 1
Warning: running command 'make -f "Makevars.win" -f "C:/R/R-31~1.1/etc/i386/Makeconf" -f "C:/R/R-31~1.1/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB_LDFLAGS='$(SHLIB_CXXLDFLAGS)' SHLIB_LD='$(SHLIB_CXXLD)' SHLIB="mypackage5.dll" OBJECTS="RcppExports.o rcppeigen_hello_world.o"' had status 2
cygwin warning:
  MS-DOS style path detected: C:/R/R-31~1.1/etc/i386/Makeconf
  Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/c/R/R-31~1.1/etc/i386/Makeconf
  CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
  Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
    http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
g++ -m32 -I"C:/R/R-31~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG    -I"C:/Users/LJH/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/Rcpp/include" -I"C:/Users/LJH/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/RcppEigen/include" -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
RcppExports.cpp: In function 'SEXPREC* mypackage5_getPIcvalue(SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP)':
RcppExports.cpp:27:68: error: expected primary-expression before ']' token
make: *** [RcppExports.o] Error 1
Warning: running command 'make -f "Makevars.win" -f "C:/R/R-31~1.1/etc/i386/Makeconf" -f "C:/R/R-31~1.1/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB_LDFLAGS='$(SHLIB_CXXLDFLAGS)' SHLIB_LD='$(SHLIB_CXXLD)' SHLIB="mypackage5.dll" OBJECTS="RcppExports.o rcppeigen_hello_world.o" symbols.rds' had status 2
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'mypackage5'
* removing 'C:/Users/LJH/Documents/mypackage5.Rcheck/mypackage5'
```

1st, I try to change `bool varIn[]` to `bool *varIn`,

```
// getPIcvalue
Rcpp::List getPIcvalue(int p, bool nest, string criteria, bool *varIn, bool findIn, int n,const MatrixXd& Y,const MatrixXd& Xf,const MatrixXd& X0,double sigma);
RcppExport SEXP mypackage5_getPIcvalue(SEXP pSEXP,SEXP nestSEXP,SEXP criSEXP,SEXP varInSEXP,SEXP findInSEXP,SEXP nSEXP,SEXP YSEXP,SEXP XfSEXP,SEXP X0SEXP,SEXP sigmaSEXP) {
BEGIN_RCPP
    SEXP __sexp_result;
    {
        Rcpp::RNGScope __rngScope;
        Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< int >::type p(pSEXP );
        Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< bool >::type nest(nestSEXP );
        Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< string >::type criteria(criSEXP );
        Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< bool >::type varIn(varInSEXP );
        Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< bool >::type findIn(findInSEXP );
        Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< int >::type n(nSEXP );
        Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< const MatrixXd& >::type Y(YSEXP );
        Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< const MatrixXd& >::type Xf(XfSEXP );
        Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< const MatrixXd& >::type X0(X0SEXP );
        Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< double >::type sigma(sigmaSEXP );
        Rcpp::List __result = getPIcvalue(p, nest, criteria, varIn, findIn, n, Y, Xf, X0, sigma);
        PROTECT(__sexp_result = Rcpp::wrap(__result));
    }
    UNPROTECT(1);
    return __sexp_result;
END_RCPP
}
```

I got this error:

```
RcppExports.cpp: In function 'SEXPREC* mypackage5_getPIcvalue(SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP)':
RcppExports.cpp:27:96: error: cannot convert 'Rcpp::traits::input_parameter<bool>::type {aka Rcpp::InputParameter<bool>}' to 'bool*' for argument '4' to 'Rcpp::List getPIcvalue(int, bool, std::string, bool*, bool, int, const MatrixXd&, const MatrixXd&, const MatrixXd&, double)'
```

2nd, I try to change `bool varIn[]` to `LogicalVector& varIn`,

```
// getPIcvalue
Rcpp::List getPIcvalue(int p, bool nest, string criteria, LogicalVector& varIn, bool findIn, int n,const MatrixXd& Y,const MatrixXd& Xf,const MatrixXd& X0,double sigma);
RcppExport SEXP mypackage5_getPIcvalue(SEXP pSEXP,SEXP nestSEXP,SEXP criSEXP,SEXP varInSEXP,SEXP findInSEXP,SEXP nSEXP,SEXP YSEXP,SEXP XfSEXP,SEXP X0SEXP,SEXP sigmaSEXP) {
BEGIN_RCPP
    SEXP __sexp_result;
    {
        Rcpp::RNGScope __rngScope;
        Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< int >::type p(pSEXP );
        Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< bool >::type nest(nestSEXP );
        Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< string >::type criteria(criSEXP );
        Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< const LogicalVector& >::type varIn(varInSEXP );
        Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< bool >::type findIn(findInSEXP );
        Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< int >::type n(nSEXP );
        Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< const MatrixXd& >::type Y(YSEXP );
        Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< const MatrixXd& >::type Xf(XfSEXP );
        Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< const MatrixXd& >::type X0(X0SEXP );
        Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< double >::type sigma(sigmaSEXP );
        Rcpp::List __result = getPIcvalue(p, nest, criteria, varIn, findIn, n, Y, Xf, X0, sigma);
        PROTECT(__sexp_result = Rcpp::wrap(__result));
    }
    UNPROTECT(1);
    return __sexp_result;
END_RCPP
}
```

error is:

```
RcppExports.cpp: In function 'SEXPREC* mypackage5_getPIcvalue(SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP)':
RcppExports.cpp:27:96: error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'Rcpp::LogicalVector& {aka Rcpp::Vector<10, Rcpp::PreserveStorage>&}' from expression of type 'Rcpp::traits::input_parameter<Rcpp::Vector<10, Rcpp::PreserveStorage> >::type {aka Rcpp::InputParameter<Rcpp::Vector<10, Rcpp::PreserveStorage> >}'
RcppExports.cpp:11:12: error: in passing argument 4 of 'Rcpp::List getPIcvalue(int, bool, std::string, Rcpp::LogicalVector&, bool, int, Eigen::MatrixXd&, Eigen::MatrixXd&, Eigen::MatrixXd&, double)'
make: *** [RcppExports.o] Error 1
Warning: running command 'make -f "Makevars.win" -f "C:/R/R-31~1.1/etc/i386/Makeconf" -f "C:/R/R-31~1.1/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB_LDFLAGS='$(SHLIB_CXXLDFLAGS)' SHLIB_LD='$(SHLIB_CXXLD)' SHLIB="mypackage5.dll" OBJECTS="RcppExports.o rcppeigen_hello_world.o"' had status 2
```

can anyone help me? Thank you in advanced.

Comment: _Minimally reproducible examples_ is the general recommendation. I don't think this corresponds to that ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rcpp attributes cannot handle array arguments like `bool varIn[]`, or pointers like `bool *varIn`.

About your attempt 2, you have some `const`ness mismatch between `getPIcvalue` that takes a `LogicalVector&` and `mypackage5_getPIcvalue` which for some reason uses a `Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< const LogicalVector& >::type`.

Did you generate `mypackage5_getPIcvalue` manually ? If yes, why ? If not, then there's a bug in Rcpp attributes.

Comment: `mypackage5_getPIcvalue` has not been generated. Sometimes, when I run `Rcmd INSTALL --build mypackage5`, `MatrixXd&` has the same error just like `LogicalVector&`.

Comment: Well a lot of effort has been put in so that the correct code is generated, if you choose not to use it, you kind of are on your own, e.g. I would not expect this to work at all. `Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< bool >::type varIn[](varInSEXP );` even if `bool[]` had been supported you would have needed `Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< bool[] >::type varIn(varInSEXP );` but as I said above it is not.

Comment: Is there documentation somewhere of exactly what is supported?

Comment: Not really. Whenever `as<T>` makes sense, you can use `T`, `T&`, `const T` and `const T&` as an input parameter.

Comment: I use `Eigen::Vector&` only including `0 and 1` to substitute `bool varIn[]`